# Vue3 TypeScript props with multiple types

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

As an exercise, I'm trying to define the [FontAwesome Vue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/blob/2.x/src/components/FontAwesomeIcon.js) implementation in TypeScript. They allow the `icon` prop to have different types:

```js
icon: {
    type: [Object, Array, String],
    required: true
},
```

I tried to add a validation to it, but then `props` in setup seems broken:

```js
validator: (prop) => {
    if (typeof prop === 'object') {
        const obj = prop as any;
        return (obj.prefix && obj.iconName);
    } else if (Array.isArray(prop) && prop.length === 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return typeof prop === 'string';
}
```

> ```
> Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ [x: number]: string; } & { length?: number | undefined; toString?: string | undefined; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; join?: string | undefined; slice?: string[] | undefined; ... 16 more ...; flat?: unknown[] | undefined; }> | Readonly<...>'.
> Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ [x: number]: string; } & { length?: number | undefined; toString?: string | undefined; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; join?: string | undefined; slice?: string[] | undefined; ... 16 more ...; flat?: unknown[] | undefined; }>'.Vetur(2339)
> ```

Without the validator, I can do this in the setup:

```js
setup(props) {
    let icon: Icon; // simple interface I defined having prefix and iconName
    if (typeof props.icon === 'object') {
        icon = props.icon as Icon;
    } else if (Array.isArray(props.icon) && props.icon.length === 2) {
        icon = {
            prefix: props.icon[0],
            iconName: props.icon[1],
        };
    } else if (typeof props.icon === 'string') {
        icon = {
            prefix: 'l',
            iconName: props.icon as string,
        };
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I could make the validation work with this setup? or is there a better way to define a prop with multiple types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple data types for VueJs Props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608244/how-to-add-multiple-data-types-for-vuejs-props)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From how I understand the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props) something like the following would be needed:

```
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

interface Icon {
  src: string
  width: number
  height: number
}

const Component = defineComponent({
  props: {
    icon: {
        type: [Object, Array, String] as PropType<Icon | Icon[] | string>,
        required: true
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Likewise for the `data` property. For example: `data(){ id: null as number | null}`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to the type.

```
{
    name: 'Bob' as string | number,
}
```