# How can I define a model in a Vue 3 component that has a type of array or string?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to use `defineModel()` with VueJs 3.4.15, Typescript and the composition API.
I want to allow the property to either be a `string[] | string`.

Unfortunately I am not able to use the pipe operator in the type specification.

```
<script setup>
const model = defineModel({ type: Array<string> | string });
</script>
```

I know it is possible since Vuetify's `v-select` does it with it's `multiple: boolean` attribute.

What would be the correct syntax to allow that?

I was able to use `defineModel()` with many other components, but I am stuck on this use case.

Answer (score 2):

In the same way [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279223/vue3-typescript-props-with-multiple-types) solves the problem.

I was able to use:

```
<script setup>
const model = defineModel({
    type: [Array<string>, String] as PropType<Array<string> | string>
});
</script>
```