# assign multi types to a property in vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have an interface

```
export interface MyRange {
  min: number
  max: number
}
```

inside a vue3 component I have a type

```
type SliderType = number | MyRange
```

and I want a property of the component, which would be the v-model, to be number or MyRange so I set

```
props: {        
    modelValue: {
        type: Object as PropType<SliderType>,
        required: true
    }
}
```

in setup I init my v-model var

```
const modelValueCopy: Ref<SliderType> = ref(props.modelValue)
```

It works but I got the ts2322 error, that SliderType can't be assigned to number | null | undefined, and Range can't be assigned to number

any idea how to fix this?

I've tried this

```
props: {        
    modelValue: {
        type: number | MyRange,
        required: true
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple data types for VueJs Props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608244/how-to-add-multiple-data-types-for-vuejs-props)

Comment: No, this doesn't work